# Manipulating data in a Multiarray in C# in Windows Form

Tags: c#, syntax

Manipulating data in a Multi-array in C# in Windows Form.
I am porting an older VB application I wrote into C# and having some difficulty understanding the syntax surrounding multi-arrays.

In VB I can DIM arrays then preload data into them

Example

```
Private Sub FormMain_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal 
eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 

Dim DataPoint_300_mCi(15, 10) As Object

DataPoint30Ci(1, 0) = 27780.4818
DataPoint30Ci(1, 1) = 13135.3365
DataPoint30Ci(1, 2) = 6552.5702
DataPoint30Ci(1, 3) = 3276.2851
DataPoint30Ci(1, 4) = 2642.1654
DataPoint30Ci(1, 5) = 1336.1808
DataPoint30Ci(1, 6) = 682.4336
DataPoint30Ci(1, 7) = 345.7462
```

(snippet of total)

Then use two variables to access the specific values in the array
I am trying to get the correct syntax in C# but having some difficulty.
I wrote a test app to understand the syntax but it’s not working. 
Basically I have two text boxes for now to enter in an x y value push a button then result goes into another text box.

I have edited it to show all code. I am an old dog trying to learn new tricks

I get an error message on textBoxAnswer.Text = DataPoint30Ci[x, y].ToString(); namely DataPoint30Ci[x, y]. The error message reads "The name 'DataPoint30Ci' does not exist in the current content.

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MultiArrayTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Double[,] DataPoint30Ci = new Double[15, 2];

        DataPoint30Ci[0, 0] = 27780.4818;
        DataPoint30Ci[0, 1] = 13135.3365;
        DataPoint30Ci[0, 2] = 6552.5702;
        DataPoint30Ci[0, 3] = 3276.2851;
        DataPoint30Ci[1, 4] = 2642.1654;
        DataPoint30Ci[1, 5] = 1336.1808;
        DataPoint30Ci[1, 6] = 682.4336;
        DataPoint30Ci[1, 7] = 345.7462;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = int.Parse(textBoxColumn1.Text);
        int y = int.Parse(textBoxColumn2.Text);
        textBoxAnswer.Text = DataPoint30Ci[x, y].ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *but it’s not working* is a terrible problem description

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sparse info (removing the brackets didn't really help) I'm gonna suggest the following: Define the `DataPoint30Ci` as a property/field of the form - something like:

```
public class Form1: Form
{
    private double[,] DataPoint30Ci;

    //rest of the code
}
```

Also make sure that the array is filled in the constructor.